# Transform Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea to WPF dimensions at higher DPI settings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dpi

I have the following function in my WPF application that I use to resize a window to the primary screen's working area (the whole screen minus the taskbar):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int theHeight = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
    int theWidth = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;

    this.MaxHeight = theHeight;
    this.MinHeight = theHeight;
    this.MaxWidth = theWidth;
    this.MinWidth = theWidth;

    this.Height = theHeight;
    this.Width = theWidth;

    this.Top = 0;
    this.Left = 0;
}
```

This works very well, as long as the machine's DPI is set at 100%.  However, if they have the DPI set higher, then this doesn't work, and the window spills off the screen.  I realize that this is because WPF pixels aren't the same as "real" screen pixels, and because I'm using a WinForms property to get the screen dimensions.

I don't know of an WPF equivalent to Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.  Is there something I can use for this that would work regardless of DPI setting?

If not, then I guess I need to some sort of scaling, but I'm not sure how to determine how much to scale by.

How can I modify my function to account for different DPI settings?

By the way, in case you're wondering why I need to use this function instead of just maximizing the window, it's because it's a borderless window (WindowStyle="None"), and if you maximize this type of window, it covers the taskbar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You get the transformed work area size from the [`SystemParameters.WorkArea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.workarea.aspx) property:

```
Top = 0;
Left = 0;
Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
```

Answer (score 3):

In WPF, you can use the [`SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.primaryscreenwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.primaryscreenheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties to find out the primary screen dimensions:

```
double width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
double height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get the dimensions of both Screens you simply can use:

```
var primaryScreen = 
   System.Windows.Forms
      .Screen
      .AllScreens
      .Where(s => s.Primary)
      .FirstOrDefault();

var secondaryScreen = 
   System.Windows.Forms
      .Screen
      .AllScreens
      .Where(s => !s.Primary)
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

---

After this you can reach Width, Height etc. by using

```
primaryScreen.Bounds.Width
```

So Long ;)