# Convert screen to WPF coordinates without showing a Window

Tags: c#, wpf

There are several answered questions on Stackoverflow about how to convert screen to WPF coordinates, if you have a visible Window available.

How can you do the conversion if you *don't* have a visible Window (for, in my case, a tray application)?

I've tried the very inelegant method of creating a hidden dummy Window,

```
var w = new Window();
w.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
presentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(w);
var transform = presentationSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
w.Close();
```

This will not work. The window `w` has to be shown, `w.Show()`, in order for `PresentationSource.FromVisual` to work. I also tried `w.PointFromScreen(point)`, but that throws an exception if the `w` is not shown.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24441443/1136211).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half of the answer is in Clemens' link in the comments above, and this is the whole answer:

First, you need to reference GetSystemMetrics in USER32, so you can get the physical screen dimensions:

```
public static int SM_CXSCREEN = 0;  // GetSystemMetrics index.
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int nIndex);
```

Then, get the ratio between WPF logical pixels and physical pixels:

```
double widthInDevicePixels = WinApi.GetSystemMetrics(WinApi.SM_CXSCREEN);
double widthInDIP = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Right; // Device independent pixels.
double scalingFactor = widthInDIP/widthInDevicePixels;
```

...and that's it:

```
double wpfLogicalPixel = devicePixel * scalingFactor;
```