# How do I get the display width and height of multiple displays in C# in .net 8.0?

Tags: c#, .net

I essentially need to convert a function that relied on Screen.PrimaryScreen and Screen.AllScreens. These are part of Windows.Forms which I cannot use in 8.0. What options do I have to get the number of monitors/displays as well as each displays resolution and position?

There is a surprising lack of information on this subject on stack overflow and Google. The only thing I've found was something suggesting I use EnumDisplayDevices from user32.dll. I have two issues with this. First, I believe there should be a solution built in to 8.0 already and I'm just incapable of finding it. Second, the function simply does not work as described, returning a series of 8 displays with no width or height.

Comment: WPF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441443/transform-screen-primaryscreen-workingarea-to-wpf-dimensions-at-higher-dpi-setti

Comment: That will work for the primary display, but I'm not seeing anything in there that gives me information on secondary displays

Comment: Why can't you use winforms in .Net 8? That seem like the simplest solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Winforms isn't usable in .net 8. Forms isn't part of the windows namespace

Comment: See the notes here: (multiple methods) [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103) -- You of course can use WinForms in .NET 8 (or any .NET version), just add `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` to the main `<PropertyGroup>`. But it's actually not needed

Comment: Are you using the WinUI3/ Windows App SDK as a sandbox app? Is that why you can't use Forms?